# How to break a video into frames using OpenCV over C++

Tags: c++, video, opencv

I am really new to openCV and I would like to break a video file that I have (*.avi) into separate frames.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [openCV: How to split a video into image sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350698/opencv-how-to-split-a-video-into-image-sequence)

Comment: The answer is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350698/opencv-how-to-split-a-video-into-image-sequence/4353483#4353483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `cvCaptureFromFile`, `cvQueryFrame` and `cvSaveImage` ! They'll do everything you need.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you happen to know how I convert the received image into gray-scale?   Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're more comfortable with using the C++ API, the VideoCapture class (see http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.2_org/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) is very convenient to use.