# Convert video feed to still frames in real time

Tags: android, opencv, video, image-processing, canny-operator

I am making an android app which detects any object in front of the user while he is walking.
I am using the canny edge detector method from openCV library to do so.

I want that whenever this method gets any edges on the screen from the video it should return some value. For this the idea is to see if there are any white pixels in the canny mode of the feed.

But I do not know how to do this with a video and if this has to be done with images then how to convert a live video to still images continuously?

Comment: If you read in a video you have the frames in your Mat. Try to do some of the tutorials to get a better understanding of OpenCV. In them is explained how to read and save video files and images. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4353483/2396315

Comment: possible duplicate of [openCV: How to split a video into image sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350698/opencv-how-to-split-a-video-into-image-sequence)