# How to use write() instead of printf()

Tags: c, console, output, system-calls

I am trying to print something on the console just by using the syscall write(). So far, it is more difficult than I thought.

The function is kept simple:

```
void writeOutput(char a, int64_t b, uint8_t c) {
    char bNew[]; // what should be the size of that array=
    while(b != 0x0000000000000000) {
      int leftover = b%10;
      bNew[i] = intToChar(leftover);
      b = b/10;
      i++;
    }
}

char intToChar(int num) {
    return '0' + num;
}
```

a should be formatted as char,  b as a decimal number and c as an octal number.

For example a possible input is:
writeOutput('a', -0xffff, 17); // ouput is "a -65535 21"

The the printed arguments should be separated by spaces and terminated by a newline to standard output. Also, I am trying to do that **without** the the functions of the **sprintf-family**. This makes it a little bit trickier.

EDIT: My question is: How is it possible to do that with write()? (Sry, missed that!)
The code is online.
EDIT2: My main problem is doing it without using the sprintf-family. I hoped you might help me.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: and why don't you want to use `printf()`?

Comment: Convert the arguments into strings and then call write.

Comment: @Kay: Honestly, I have been trying to implement that, but I failed so far. I hoped, someone may help me.

Comment: Hints for itoa() here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440726/what-is-the-proper-way-of-implementing-a-good-itoa-function Look at the second answer.

Comment: @Stuart: I did try this. But I got very weird results like rectangles with question marks.

Comment: You could just use `sprintf` to create the string and then pass it to write.

Comment: What is wrong with sprintf?

Comment: Here's another good reference. ( Be careful, some of these have bugs ) http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/~slowe/cpp/itoa.html

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with sprintf or printf. I already did this with printf. But I was also trying to do that with write().

Comment: If you show the code that you wrote to do this, maybe you will get some advice.

Comment: My main problem is to that without the sprintf-family. That's why I am asking you for help.

Comment: Not using any of the members of the `printf()`-family of functions would force you to write your own format parser, which is not a simple task. If it's however only for `%c` (`char`), `%ld` (`long signed int`) and `%hhu` (`unsigned char`) it might be feasable.

Comment: @alk: When I declare char bNew[10] I get the error that it is undeclared. Also an error which says: conflicting types for 'intToChar'.
Do you know why?

Comment: You declare `bNew` as `char[]`  which is quiet unspecific. You' d need a `char[19+1]` to store a signed 64bit integer as a C-"string", as the maximum possible value is `9223372036854775807` plus the necessary `0`-terminator. Btw: the `while` in your source snippet seems to be missing the braces.

Comment: Just change `char bNew[];` to be `char bNew[19+1] = "";`

Comment: @alk: You are right. This helped to get rid of the error. But I still get the error message: conflicting types for 'intToChar'
Do you know that also?

Comment: Change `int leftover = b%10;` to be `char leftover = b%10;` and `char intToChar(int num) ` to be `char intToChar(char num)`.

Comment: @alk: Unfortunately, it did not help. I still get the same error.

Comment: Why do I get this error message anyway?

Comment: It seems the code misses a prototype for `intToChar()`. Add `char intToChar(<what_ever_type_you_put:here> num);` before its 1st usage, that is at least before the declaration of `writeOutput()`.

Comment: @alk: Thanks alk. This was causing the error message.

Answer (score 1):

you can call the `write()` with first argument which is an fd as stdout. it will write to the stdout and which is your console. but before that you need have a string buffer for that you can use `sprintf' or`snprintf`with the same formatting as`printf`. but the printf way is easier and it should serve the purpose unless you have some very special use case.

Comment: The questioner specifically says he/she doesn't want to use the functions of the sprintf family.

Comment: Of course, it possible with sprintf, but is it not possible without using functions of the sprintf-family?

Comment: @user2965601 you could write your own `printf` family.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unistd.h> 
 
int main(void) { 
    write(1,"Hello World!", 12); 
    return 0; 
}
```